# How to insert a string into another one on the last matched element?

Tags: php, regex

I want to insert the string `preview/` after the first forward slash from the left. So a string like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/343333
```

will become:

```
http://www.mysite.com/preview/343333
```

How do I do that with PHP?

Comment: Those slashes are forward.

Comment: @bjb568 fixed the title

Comment: You want to redirect the URL?

Comment: He wants to modify a String, and he wants us to work for him, which I won't do

Comment: Look into [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url), add your prefix, then reassemble. Or investigate regex.

Comment: @mario it's a string.. it doesn't have to be a link

Comment: @Lucio true you caught it

Comment: What's the expected output for a URL like `http://example.org/one/two/three`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace):

```
preg_replace("/(.*)\/(\d+)$/", '$1/preview/$2', "http://www.mysite.com/343333")
```

Comment: preg_replace("/http:\/\/(.*)\/(\d+)$/", '$1/preview/$2', "http://www.test.com/343333")    I corrected your regex

Comment: it wont work for strings that have multiple slashes such as 'first/second/third/22233'

Comment: @leblma, yeah I was thinking about that but with the slash in question and "it's a string...doesn't have to be a link" I did not include the `http...` portion.

Comment: @Tom, yes it does, please check [the fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ik3-d86).

Answer (score 0):

This works-

```
$str = "http://www.mysite.com/343333";
$arr = explode("/",$str);
array_splice($arr, count($arr)-1, 0, array('preview'));
$str = implode("/",$arr);
print_r($str);
//Outputs - http://www.mysite.com/preview/343333
```

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be the most straightforward way:

```
$url = sprintf('%s/preview/%s', dirname($url), basename($url));
```